# Have I written anything wrong in my code for array_shift function?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value

My associative array called `$data` is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [op] => add
    [main_op] => 
    [rebate_id] => 
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [company_id] => 42
    [product_id] => 36
    [applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => multiselect-all
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 4
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 5
                )
       )
)
```

I want to shift the array $data['applicable_states'] backwards by one. For it I wrote following code but it's not working. Would you please help me in correcting the error I made in the code? Following is my code.

```
if (array_search('multiselect-all', $data['applicable_states']) === 0) 
        array_shift($data['applicable_states']);
```

The expected output array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [op] => add
    [main_op] => 
    [rebate_id] => 
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [company_id] => 42
    [product_id] => 36
    [applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 4
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 5
                )
       )
)
```

Comment: Please explain you problem, it is not clear what you want to acheieve - perhaps show your expected output array

Comment: @user574632:I've added the desired output array.

Comment: i don't see a different

Comment: @ins0:Take a look at array $data['applicable_states']. It's different.

Comment: `array_shift($data['applicable_states']);` should works. @ins0 He wants to remove the first element in the array `applicable_states`.

Comment: @ins0: No, it isn't. The output is missing the first array element where `state_id => multiselect-all`.

Comment: @Debflav:You exactly got my problem. But I want to do this only when the 0th key state_id contains value [state_id] => multiselect-all. Otherwise no need to do any changes. Cna you help me in this regard please?

Comment: @Cory yeah saw it after my false quick comment ;)

Comment: `if ([applicable_states][0][state_id] === 'multiselect-all')` [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the value

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem with your code - you have complex array so it won't work - `array_search` won't find the value (will always return false)

As solution, you should simple use:

```
if ($data['applicable_states'][0]['state_id'] == 'multiselect-all') {
    array_shift($data['applicable_states']);   
}
```

Comment: -1: `array_shift` returns the shifted value, not the shortened array.

Answer (score 0):

like your answer and the given data, you can simple `array_map` and the `array_filter` to toss the element with your given specifications.

```
$data['applicable_states'] = array_filter(array_map(function($v){
    return ($v['state_id'] != 'multiselect-all') ? $v : null;
}, $data['applicable_states']));
```

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php